# Concurrent message consumption in ActiveMQ

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, message-queue, messaging

I use a *ActiveMQServer* as a broker.

**Server.java**

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.activemq.api.core.TransportConfiguration;
import org.apache.activemq.core.config.Configuration;
import org.apache.activemq.core.config.impl.ConfigurationImpl;
import org.apache.activemq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyAcceptorFactory;
import org.apache.activemq.core.server.ActiveMQServer;
import org.apache.activemq.core.server.ActiveMQServers;

public class Server {
    public static void main(final String arg[]) throws Exception
    {
        try
        {
            // Step 1. Create the Configuration, and set the properties accordingly
            Configuration configuration = new ConfigurationImpl();
            //we only need this for the server lock file
            configuration.setJournalDirectory("target/data/journal");
            configuration.setPersistenceEnabled(false); // http://activemq.apache.org/what-is-the-difference-between-persistent-and-non-persistent-delivery.html
            configuration.setSecurityEnabled(false); // http://activemq.apache.org/security.html
            /**
             * this map with configuration values is not necessary (it configures the default values).
             * If you want to modify it to run the example in two different hosts, remember to also
             * modify the client's Connector at {@link EmbeddedRemoteExample}.
             */
            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            map.put("host", "localhost");
            map.put("port", 61616);

            // https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/5/html/HornetQ_User_Guide/ch14s04.html
            TransportConfiguration transpConf = new TransportConfiguration(NettyAcceptorFactory.class.getName(),map);

            HashSet<TransportConfiguration> setTransp = new HashSet<TransportConfiguration>();
            setTransp.add(transpConf);

            configuration.setAcceptorConfigurations(setTransp); // https://github.com/apache/activemq-6/blob/master/activemq-server/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/spi/core/remoting/Acceptor.java

            // Step 2. Create and start the server
            ActiveMQServer server = ActiveMQServers.newActiveMQServer(configuration);
            server.start();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

and I have a **Client.java** class, where I create a queue, message producer and message consumer.

**Client.java**

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.activemq.api.core.ActiveMQException;
import org.apache.activemq.api.core.SimpleString;
import org.apache.activemq.api.core.TransportConfiguration;
import org.apache.activemq.api.core.client.ActiveMQClient;
import org.apache.activemq.api.core.client.ClientConsumer;
import org.apache.activemq.api.core.client.ClientMessage;
import org.apache.activemq.api.core.client.ClientProducer;
import org.apache.activemq.api.core.client.ClientSession;
import org.apache.activemq.api.core.client.ClientSessionFactory;
import org.apache.activemq.api.core.client.MessageHandler;
import org.apache.activemq.api.core.client.ServerLocator;
import org.apache.activemq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnectorFactory;

public class Client
{

    private static final String queueName = "queue.exampleQueue";
    private static final String propName = "myprop";

    ClientSessionFactory sf = null;
    ClientSession session = null;
    ClientProducer producer = null;
    ClientMessage message = null;
    ClientConsumer consumer = null;
    String name;

    public Client(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void initializeComponents(){ 

        try
          {          
            // Step 3. As we are not using a JNDI environment we instantiate the objects directly

             /**
              * this map with configuration values is not necessary (it configures the default values).
              * If you modify it to run the example in two different hosts, remember to also modify the
              * server's Acceptor at {@link EmbeddedServer}
              */
             Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
             map.put("host", "localhost");
             map.put("port", 61616);
             // -------------------------------------------------------

             ServerLocator serverLocator = ActiveMQClient.createServerLocatorWithoutHA(new TransportConfiguration(NettyConnectorFactory.class.getName(), map));
             sf = serverLocator.createSessionFactory();

             // Step 4. Create a core queue
             ClientSession coreSession = sf.createSession(false, false, false);

             if (!coreSession.queueQuery(new SimpleString(queueName)).isExists())
                 coreSession.createTemporaryQueue(queueName, queueName);

             coreSession.close();

            // Step 5. Create the session, and producer
            session = sf.createSession();

            producer = session.createProducer(queueName); // 

            // Step 7. Create the message consumer and start the connection
            consumer = session.createConsumer(queueName); 
            session.start();

            // Step 8. Receive the message.
            consumer.setMessageHandler(new MessageHandler(){

                public void onMessage(ClientMessage message)
                {
                    System.out.println("client " + name + " received message " + message.getStringProperty(propName));
                }

            });

          }
          catch (Exception e)
          {
             e.printStackTrace();
          }

    }

    public void sendMessage(String messageText){

        // Step 6. Create and send a message
        message = session.createMessage(false);
        message.putStringProperty(propName, messageText);

        try {
            System.out.println("Producer is going to send a message");
            producer.send(message);
        } catch (ActiveMQException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void cleanUpConnection(){
        if (sf != null)
        {
           sf.close();
        }
    }

}
```

In this main I create one queue, two producers and two consumers.

```
       public static void main(final String[] args)
   {
       Client cl1 = new Client("cl1");
       cl1.initializeComponents();

       Client cl2 = new Client("cl2");
       cl2.initializeComponents();

       for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
           try {

               Date date = new Date();
               String formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(date);

               cl1.sendMessage(formattedDate + " number of iteration " + i);
               Thread.sleep(2000);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

   }

       cl1.cleanUpConnection();
       cl2.cleanUpConnection();

   }
```

and this is the output of main:

```
Producer is going to send a message
client cl1 received message 05/06/2015 16:56:22 number of iteration 0
Producer is going to send a message
client cl2 received message 05/06/2015 16:56:24 number of iteration 1
Producer is going to send a message
client cl1 received message 05/06/2015 16:56:26 number of iteration 2
Producer is going to send a message
client cl2 received message 05/06/2015 16:56:28 number of iteration 3
Producer is going to send a message
client cl1 received message 05/06/2015 16:56:30 number of iteration 4
Producer is going to send a message
client cl2 received message 05/06/2015 16:56:32 number of iteration 5
Producer is going to send a message
client cl1 received message 05/06/2015 16:56:34 number of iteration 6
Producer is going to send a message
client cl2 received message 05/06/2015 16:56:36 number of iteration 7
Producer is going to send a message
client cl1 received message 05/06/2015 16:56:38 number of iteration 8
Producer is going to send a message
client cl2 received message 05/06/2015 16:56:40 number of iteration 9
client cl2 received message 05/06/2015 16:56:22 number of iteration 0
client cl2 received message 05/06/2015 16:56:26 number of iteration 2
client cl2 received message 05/06/2015 16:56:30 number of iteration 4
client cl2 received message 05/06/2015 16:56:34 number of iteration 6
client cl2 received message 05/06/2015 16:56:38 number of iteration 8
```

I would like to ask, how can I make concurrent message consumption for all consumers.

I mean:

```
client cl1 received ... message of iteration 0
client cl2 received ... message of iteration 0
client cl1 received ... message of iteration 1
client cl2 received ... message of iteration 1
```

I found [prefetch limit](http://activemq.apache.org/what-is-the-prefetch-limit-for.html) settings, but don't know how to use **ActiveMQConnectionFactory** and **ActiveMQConnection** classes without refactoring in **client.java** class. Is there any other options to make message consumption concurrent for all consumers?

Comment: You are only sending a single message per iteration, thus only a single client will receive a message. If you want each client to receive the same messages, use a topic instead of a queue.

Comment: @krautmeyer you are right, can post it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only sending a single message per iteration, thus only a single client will receive a message. If you want each client to receive the same messages, use a topic instead of a queue.